# Обрезать число после второго знака после запятой

Tags: javascript

Нужно обрезать число поле второго знака после запятой, но в зависимосити от локали разделитель может быть разный.

```
10.8976 -> 10.89
10,8976 -> 10,89
```

Метод `toFixed()` именно округляет а мне нужно отрезать

Как это сделать попроще и покороче без сторонних библиотек?

Comment: `'10,8987'.match(/^\d+[,|.]\d{2}/g)[0]`, хотя немного не продумал вариант с `e`.

Comment: @ЮрийКопоть, вместо `parseInt` лучше `Math.trunc`, как минимум аргумент не будет приводиться сначала в строку. Во втором варианте может быть ошибка: `10.8999.toFixed( 3 ).slice( 0, -1 )` выдаст `10.90` вместо `10.89`

Comment: И там еще в первом комменте регулярку изменить на `/^\d+[,|.]\d{0,2}/g`, чтобы проходили такие варианты: `0,2 либо 10.9` - т.е. с одной цифрой после запятой.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var x = 10.8976456874;

console.log( Math.trunc( x * 100 ) / 100 );
```

Answer (score 1):

Ну в JS у чисел нет "запятой", только точка. Поэтому:

```js
var x = 10.8976456874;

console.log( Math.floor( x * 100 ) / 100 );
```

Math.floor() округляет до нижнего целого числа.

А если в тексте встречаются такие числа, и запятые тоже надо учитывать, тогда придется через регулярные выражения:

```js
var x = "Число: 10.8976456874, Второе: 58974,1547, Третье: 10.1";

x = x.replace(/(\d+)(\.|,)(\d+)/g, function(o, a, b, c){
  // Где o = всё совпадение целиком, a, b и с = совпадения из 1-й, 2-й и 3-й скобок.
  // символ \d находит совпадение с любой цифрой. Плюсик после него означает "один или несколько"
  return a + b + c.slice(0,2);
});

console.log( x );
```