# Как сделать чтобы после запятой оставались только 2 знака без округления и с наценкой 20%?

Tags: vue.js

```
  WithdrawOpenModal(i, id, name, price, priceWithMargin, image) {
 this.withdraw.item.i = i;
 this.withdraw.item.id = id;
 this.withdraw.item.name = name;
 this.withdraw.item.price = price;
 this.withdraw.item.priceWithMargin = Number((price * 1.202).toFixed(2));
 this.withdraw.modal = true;
```

Есть строчка `this.withdraw.item.priceWithMargin = Number((price * 1.202).toFixed(2));`
она выводит стоимость предмета, с наценкой +- 20%, из-за того, что цена айтема допустим 124, она выводит не 149.04, а 149.05, можете помочь со строчкой, что бы была наценка на предмет была 20% +
БЕЗ округления. и после запятой было 2 знака

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Обрезать число после второго знака после запятой](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1006221/%d0%9e%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5-%d0%b2%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%8f%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b9)

Comment: А вы точно программист? (с) ...

Comment: Вы же задавали этот вопрос [про округление чисел](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1543510/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%87%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8b-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%8f%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%8c-%d1%82%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%ba%d0%be-2-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%b1%d0%b5%d0%b7-%d0%be%d0%ba%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b3%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f/1543526#1543526). Какой смысл в новом?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как сделать чтобы после запятой оставались только 2 знака без округления?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1543510/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%87%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8b-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%8f%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%8c-%d1%82%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%ba%d0%be-2-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%b1%d0%b5%d0%b7-%d0%be%d0%ba%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b3%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f)